# SharePoint 2010 Web Part, not displaying list total

Tags: 2010, list-view

I have a SharePoint List and if I include a total on the view of a column, it displays correctly. However, if I use the same view and include it on a page as a web part, it doesn't display.

Any ideas? I've looked over all the settings and I'm missing something.

Comment: Have you checkined and published the page?

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution on this, anyone have any more insight?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the web part and click "Edit the current view".  Set the totalling options you want there.  It is possible that it is displaying a different view when you add the web part.

Comment: I have changed that setting on the current view, however, it's still not displaying. This is the interesting part and why I posted it here.